# Performance comparison of these two queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization

I am using this query to get result, where `Calander` (primary key: `DAY_DATE`) has all continuous information about time (i.e. date, quarter, year etc.) and `EXPENCE` and `INCOME` both have column `TXN_DATE` as a foreign key to `DAY_DATE`.

```
  SELECT
    COALESCE(t1."FISCAL_YEAR",t2."FISCAL_YEAR") "FISCAL_YEAR" ,
    "exp" "exp" ,
    "rev" "rev" 
    FROM
    (SELECT
    Calander.FISCAL_YEAR "FISCAL_YEAR" ,
    (SUM("EXPENCE"."TXN_AMT" )) "exp" 
    FROM
        Calander ,
        EXPENCE 
    WHERE
        "EXPENCE"."TXN_DATE"="Calander"."DAY_DATE" 
    GROUP BY 
        FISCAL_YEAR ) t1 FULL OUTER JOIN (SELECT
        Calander.FISCAL_YEAR "FISCAL_YEAR" ,
        (SUM("INCOME"."TXN_AMT" )) "rev" 
    FROM
        Calander ,
        INCOME 
    WHERE
        "INCOME"."TXN_DATE"="Calander"."DAY_DATE" 
    GROUP BY 
        FISCAL_YEAR ) t2 ON 
        t1."FISCAL_YEAR"=t2."FISCAL_YEAR"  
    ORDER BY
            COALESCE(t1."FISCAL_YEAR",t2."FISCAL_YEAR")
```

Now to make query more simple to understand I did this

```
SELECT
    FISCAL_YEAR "FISCAL_YEAR" ,
    (sum("EXPENCE"."TXN_AMT" )) "exp",
    (sum("INCOME"."TXN_AMT" )) "rev" 
FROM
    Calander ,
    EXPENCE FULL OUTER JOIN INCOME ON
    "EXPENCE"."TXN_DATE" = "INCOME"."TXN_DATE"
WHERE
    "EXPENCE"."TXN_DATE"="Calander"."DAY_DATE" and
    "INCOME"."TXN_DATE"="Calander"."DAY_DATE" 
GROUP BY 
    FISCAL_YEAR
ORDER BY
    FISCAL_YEAR
```

I am getting same result in both queries. Will the result will be difference in any case (Ist query result is the correct result)?
What will be performance impact?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (more than **20 years** ago)

Comment: @marc_s any idea why people still use this style today although it is discouraged everywhere? I'm honestly curious about that.

Comment: @usr: I'm afraid a lot of instructors aren't really up to date and teach the "old" style - or just pure lazyness "been doing this like this for 20 years......"

Answer (score 1):

Second one should be more efficient, but to verify it, check actual execution plans. Also set the

```
SET STATISTICS IO ON
```

on the session and check the logical reads for both queries on your real data.

Another habit to kick - stop using double quotes around identifiers, or prepare to get hit by QUOTED_IDENTIFIER setting sometime :)

Comment: Statistics wise for small dataset second is more efficient. But can you please explain the reason? Will result will always same in any case?

Comment: Subqueries in the first one are executed as separate branches, I believe, so two scans of the Calendar table and two agregations. The second one will probably be better optimized in most cases. But, as always, it depends on the data distribution and cardinality, and the existing indexes.

Comment: EXPENCE and INCOME table may contain so many rows in production system, will it cause Cartesian join between these two table, if I choose second query?

Answer (score 0):

The second query will be better performance-wise.
In your first query,you are using joins in the two sub-queries to filter the data and then again joining them whereas your second query is more optimized as you are filtering the data by joining all the three tables.One more suggestion,avoid using old style joins to make your queries readable and better.